# If $\lambda$ is in the continous spectrum of $L$, then the range of $L-\lambda$ can not be closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let the continuous spectrum of a densely defined linear operator $L$ over a Separable Hilbert space, be defined as the set of all $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that:

(i) $L-\lambda$ is injective,

(ii) The closure of the range of $L-\lambda$ is the whole Hilbert space,

(iii) The inverse of $L-\lambda$ (with range of $L-\lambda$ as the domain) is not bounded.

(This definition is taken from the book "Principles and Techniques of Applied Mathematics" by Bernard Friedman.)

Then, prove or provide counter-example to the following statement: If $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum of $L$, then the range of $L-\lambda$ can not be closed.

If the above statement is not true, is it true under the additional assumption that $L$ is a bounded linear operator?

Comment: According to Rudin (FA book) the continuous spectrum consists of all $\lambda$ such that $L-\lambda$  is injective with  the range a   dense **proper** subspace. So the range is obviously not closed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So I guess the question is can we trade unbounded inverse in the definition here for Rudin's range being proper subspace but dense.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ belongs to the continuous spectrum then the image of $\lambda I-T$ is a dense proper subset of the space (see [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis))).
Thus it cannot be closed by definition.

What follows is an example where $0$ belongs to the essential spectrum, the image is equal to the whole space and both $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are unbounded.
Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Hamel basis in $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{B}_0=\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ its countable subset. Define an operator $T:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ by the formula
$$Tb=\begin{cases} {1\over n}b_{n} & b=b_n\\
b & b\notin \mathcal{B}_0\end{cases} $$
and extend linearly to the whole space. The inverse operator $S$ is defined by the formula
$$Sb=\begin{cases} nb_{n} & b=b_n\\
b & b\notin \mathcal{B}_0\end{cases} $$ Consider $\lambda =0.$
The operator $T$ is injective and $T(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{H}$ The range of $T$ is thus closed. The inverse operator $S$ is unbounded (as well as $T$ is unbounded).

Comment: Yess, $\lambda=0.$ Do you want the inverse is defined on the whole space or on the range of $T$ ?

Comment: I have re-edited the answer. Now the range is not full. For simplicity I consider a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @duality It is not closed because $b_1$ does not belong to the range.

Comment: What's wrong with my example ? It seems the operator satisfies your requirements. The range is dense as it contains an orthonormal basis. The range is not closed as it is a proper subset of  the space. The operator is injective and the inverse is unbounded.

Comment: I do not get it. My first example had the closed range $T(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{H}.$ Then you made a comment that it was not a counterexample because the range was closed. I am unable to make the range closed and not closed at the same time. I will modify back the example to make the range closed.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda$ were in the continuous spectrum, and if the range of $L-\lambda I$ were closed, then the range would be $\mathcal{H}$, and the inverse $(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$ would be continuous by the closed graph theorem. But that would force $\lambda$ to be in the resolvent set, not in the continuous spectrum.